# How do I convert an Exodus CSV private key export to JSON for Mist?

Tags: wallets

I have a csv file that was [exported from the EXODUS app](http://support.exodus.io/article/86-how-can-i-view-my-private-keys) with the following columns:

> ADDRESS   PATH    BALANCE PRIVKEY

Is there a way to get this into *json* format standard so that I can import it in [Ethereum Wallet](https://ethereum.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full process, if you want to move from Exodus to Mist using just the "Developer -> Assets -> Ethereum -> Export Private Keys" menu is this:

1. Take the private key in the PRIVKEY section and put it in a file on your desktop. Let's call it `privatekey`.
2. Use `geth` to import the account. If you're on macOS:

   ```
   $ geth import account privatekey
   ```
3. Geth will prompt you to create a password for the account and import it.

   ```
   Your new account is locked with a password.
   Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
   Passphrase:
   Repeat passphrase:
   Address: {39bd6536020d2b25006257064dd339d2a748f664}
   ```

You could try to replicate the JSON format, but I don't recommend it. I pulled the instructions [from this wiki article](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens#How_To_Import_A_Private_Key_Into_Go_Ethereum_.28geth.29) and verified that they work with both the latest versions of Mist and Exodus.